# Adjusting points in 'Stroke Method: Curve'

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to understand how stroke method: curve works in sculpting mode, because it seems to act differently than a standard bezier curve you would add to a scene. And I've come across no documentation on how to use it.

I have the basics down but one annoying aspect is my points keep overlapping, such as in the far left of this pic, and I don't know how to separate them. It would also be useful to know if there's a way to make the two points equidistant and 'balanced' after one arm has been adjusted.

[image]

Comment: This is indeed a weak area - suggest to propose changes on http://rightclickselect.com